# How do you set up PHP 5.4.0 using Web Platform Installer on Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, php5

I just installed PHP 5.4.0 on Windows 2008 using the Web Platform Installer, but I still get 404s anytime I try to request a php.  Anyone know where Microsoft has hidden the install/setup documentation for their build of PHP 5.4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's Web Platform Installer installs PHP 5.4.0 with an invalid configuration.
IIS 7.5's Manager (and probably all older versions too) can't handle Handler Mappings that point to .exe files that have spaces in the path unless the path is surrounded by ""

So to fix it, you just have to go into Handler Mappings in Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, pick Handler Mappings, then pick PHP54_via_FastCGI then pick Edit... and then surround the entry that Web Platform Installer made for "Executatble (optional):" with "", ie: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe"